# Why can't JAXB find my jaxb.index when running inside Apache Felix?

Tags: java, jaxb, osgi, apache-felix

It's right there, in the package that it should be indexing. Still, when I call

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package.name");
```

I get a JAXBException saying that

> "my.package.name" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

although it does contain both.

What does work, but isn't quite what I want, is

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(my.package.name.SomeClass.class);
```

This question from various other people appears on quite some mailing lists and forums but seemingly doesn't get answers.

I'm running this on OpenJDK 6, so I got the source packages and stepped my debugger into the library. It starts by looking for jaxb.properties, then looks for system properties and failing to find either, it tries to create the default context using com.sun.internal.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory. In there, the Exception gets thrown (inside `ContextFactor.createContext(String ClassLoader, Map)`), but I can't see what's going on because the source isn't here.

**ETA**:

Judging from the source code for ContentFactory, I found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-com.sun/xml/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/ContextFactory.java.htm#createContextStringClassLoaderMapStringObject), this is probably the piece of code that fails to work as intended:

```
/**
 * Look for jaxb.index file in the specified package and load it's contents
 *
 * @param pkg package name to search in
 * @param classLoader ClassLoader to search in
 * @return a List of Class objects to load, null if there weren't any
 * @throws IOException if there is an error reading the index file
 * @throws JAXBException if there are any errors in the index file
 */
private static List<Class> loadIndexedClasses(String pkg, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException, JAXBException {
    final String resource = pkg.replace('.', '/') + "/jaxb.index";
    final InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resource);

    if (resourceAsStream == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

From my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034132/can-i-put-annotations-for-multiple-processors-into-a-java-class) [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037356/how-do-i-debug-silent-failures-in-java-applications), I'm guessing that this has to do with the class loading mechanisms of the OSGi container that this is running in. Unfortunately, I am still a little out of my depth here.

Comment: I meant please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: The post is getting a little long already, but I've already tracked the origin of the exception, just posted this above.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

OK, this took quite some digging, but the answer is not that surprising and not even that complicated:

**JAXB can't find jaxb.index, because by default, `newInstance(String)` uses the current thread's class loader (as returned by `Thread.getContextClassLoader()`). This doesn't work inside Felix, because the OSGi bundles and the framework's threads have separate class loaders.**

The solution is to get a suitable class loader from somewhere and use `newInstance(String, ClassLoader)`. I got a suitable class loader from one of the classes in the package that contains `jaxb.index`, a sensible choice for flexibility reasons probably is `ObjectFactory`:

```
ClassLoader cl = my.package.name.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.package.name", cl);
```

Maybe you could also get at the class loader that the `Bundle` instance is using, but I couldn't figure out how, and the above solution seems safe to me.

Comment: This actually turns out to generally be a quite nasty problem in OSGi environments when you're using libraries that aren't designed for OSGi and make assumptions about the classloader they get. This issue is why people claim that Eclipselink is the only JPA provider that works in OSGi (don't know if that's still true).

Comment: ContextClassLoader; When setting the classloader, you should first check to see if there's one already set, if so hold it as local variable and then reset it in a finally block after your call to JAX - you don't know what else is using classloader hacks...

Comment: Is there a Jira item related to this issue? we stumbled here and i can attest that the solution works, i am just wondering if this is an awknowledged issue from apache-felix project

Comment: @Monachus - This is not really a Felix issue, it's more that OSGi *in general* creates this type of problem for libraries that suddenly get used in an OSGi context without ever having been designed for it. This is by design really (OSGi is a lot about separating classloaders), so it's not something the OSGi container could, or even should attempt to, fix.

Comment: Thanks for that! A little optimazation: 
Class<ObjectFactory> c = my.package.name.ObjectFactory.class;
ClassLoader cl = c.getClassLoader();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(c.getPackage().getName(), cl);

So you won't have problems with renaming packages.

Comment: @HannoFietz I have a similar issue,and tried to use your code but I do not have jaxb.index how can I have that in a class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue with the project I am working on. After reading http://jaxb.java.net/faq/index.html#classloader I realized that JAXBContext is not able to find the package containing jaxb.index.

I will try to make this as clear as possible.

We have

```
Bundle A
   -- com.a
      A.java
        aMethod()
        {
            B.bMethod("com.c.C");
        }
MANIFEST.MF
Import-Package: com.b, com.c         

Bundle B
   -- com.b
      B.java
        bmethod(String className)
        {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        }

Export-Package: com.b

Bundle C
   -- com.c
      C.java
        c()
        {
            System.out.println("hello i am C");
        }

Export-Package: com.c
```

To relate to **JAXB**. **class B is JAXBContext and bMethod is newInstance()**

If you are familiar with OSGi package restrictions then it must be very clear now that **Bundle B** is not Importing package **com.c** i.e **class C** is **not visible** to **class B** hence it cannot instantiate C.

The solution would be to pass a **ClassLoader** to bMethod. This ClassLoader should come from a **bundle that is importing com.c**. In this case we can pass **A.class.getClassLoader()** since **bundle A is importing com.c**

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For the same problem, I resolved it by manually putting the package into the import.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven in your project, then just use this library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It's created for Glasfish server but also working with Tomcat (checked).
With this library you can easly use JAXB with OSGI bundles.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**

I once had similar strange class loading problem in my application. If I run it as a normal application, everything was OK but when I invoked it as a Windows Service, it started to fail with ClassNotFoundExceptions. The analysis showed that the threads have their classloaders as null somehow. I solved the problem by setting the SystemClassLoader on the threads:

```
// ...
thread.setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
thread.start();
// ...
```

Don't know if your container allows this kind of change though.

Comment: Well, it might (I don't know), but it seems to me that there should be some place where I can put the file so that the classloader used does find it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this issue. For me, the solution was to use IBM's JRE instead of Oracle's. Seems like the JAXB implementation is more OSGI-friendly in that one.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully resolved this by adding the package of my generated classes containing `ObjectFactory` to the `<Private-Package>` part of my bundle definition, plus `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.*`

Answer (score 0):

There may be another scenario which can give this problem.

When you install and start a bundle which export the package that contains the jaxb.index or objectFactory.java

Then please make sure that the bundles importing the classes are stopped or pointing to the correct package name.

Also check the export and import statements in the pom.xml

Faced similar issue in servicemix(karaf) osgi container

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that a unit test which was not related to the module that I have developed did not had a dependency in it pom.xml to my module.
The UT still recognized my module due to fetching the packages list from shared configuration file.

When running the UT it didn't compile the new module so it didn't generate the ObjectFactory.java therefore I received the error even though when I compiled the module I was able to see the ObjectFactory.java

added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-module-name</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

My Solution was:

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(**new Class[]{"my.package.name"}**);

OR

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(**new Class[]{class.getName()}**);

OR

a full solution:

```
public static <T> T deserializeFile(Class<T> _class, String _xml) {

        try {

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{_class});
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

            File file = new File(_xml);
            Object obj = um.unmarshal(file);

            return _class.cast(obj);

        } catch (JAXBException exc) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Works 100%